# mono could not find asp.net server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, mono

I have built Mono from github yesterday to usr/local prefix. I have chosen this directory as a default in my Xamarin Mono runtime version (now it became Mono  4.3.0). But after that when I ran my project I got an error message saying "Mono could not find ASP.Net web server. The xsp4 web server could not be found.". Did I do something wrong or what should I do now? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360841/monodevelop-doesnt-find-xsp4-web-server-although-it-is-installed-running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSP is another Git repository to clone and build,

https://github.com/mono/xsp

There are also other Git repository for Mono components, so if you do prefer to build your own other than using the Xamarin's, make sure you spend enough time going through the README files and wish you good luck.